# Select Random Max in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
id    name    bid
1     Test1   5.50
2     Test2   5.50
3     Test3   5.49
```

I want to select the row with the highest bid. If the highest bid is equal on another row, then it should randomly select one of the highest bid rows.

I tried:

```
SELECT name,max(bid) FROM table ORDER BY rand()
```

The output:

```
id    name    bid
1     Test1   5.50
```

My problem is that id "2" is never displayed because for some reason my query is only selecting id "1"

Comment: sigh.  how does it fail?  Man, I get tired of asking this question.

Comment: Hang in there, Paul. Your skills are highly valuable and direly needed.

Comment: My bad. You are right. I've updated my question with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECTing `name` and `MAX(bid)` in the same query makes no sense: you are asking for the highest bid aggregated across all the rows, plus a name that's not aggregated, so it's not at all clear which row's name you'll be picking. MySQL typically picks the “right” answer you meant (one of the rows that owned the maximum bid) but it's not guaranteed, fails in all other databases, and is invalid in ANSI SQL.

To get *a* highest-bid row, order by bid and pick only the first result. If you want to ensure you get a random highest-bid row rather than just an arbitrary one, add a random factor to the order clause:

```
SELECT name, bid
FROM table
ORDER BY bid DESC, RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You rock! This answer is slightly more optimized than Flimzy and MatTheCat's answers.

Comment: This answer is _less_ optimized than the answers provided by me and MatTheCat.... read the article linked in my answer to understand why.

Comment: Flimzy's answer = Query took 0.0056 sec ----
bobince's answer = Query took 0.0032 sec

Comment: @reefine If you need a performance then this query is not the way to go. But it looks really pretty. It optimized for code reader :)

Comment: As far as performance, there are only 3-5 rows being searched with the ORDER BY, so the performance is better. Am I right in this assumption? (I am a performance n00b)

Comment: @reefine Yeah, it is very likely that on small tables this is faster.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name,bid
FROM table
WHERE bid=(SELECT max(bid) FROM table)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

should do the trick. Waiting for more optimized request ^^

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're using an aggregate function, which collapses everything into a single row.  You need a sub-select:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE bid = (SELECT MAX(bid) FROM table)
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1;
```

But also be aware of [why not to use ORDER BY RAND()](http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/).  Although if you have only a few results, the performance implications may not be significant enough to bother changing.